# Can we store key-sorted data in redis, so that we dont have to actually store the key and can use position/index as key?

Tags: redis, redis-py

I have a data set that has key,values like:
0:..
1:...
2:...
.
.
.
n:...

There are no gaps in the keys.

Can we store key-sorted data in redis, so that we dont have to actually store the key and can use position/index as key ?

Looks like there is no need to store the key actually  to save memory.
How to do that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Redis LIST to save the data, and use index to get them back.

However, unless most of your operations deal with the head or tail of the list, you might get performance issues, especially when the list grows very large.

Because the time complexity of accessing items in list is O(N), where N is the index/position of the item.